# What is wrong in my answer relating Todd-Coxeter Algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is:

A triangle group $G^{pqr}$ is a group $<x,y,z|x^p,y^q,z^r,xyz>$, where $p \leq q \leq r$ are positive integers. In each case, prove that the triangle group is isomorphic to the group listed.

a) The dihedral group $D_n$, where p, q, r = 2, 2, n,

b) The octahedral group, when p, q, r = 2, 3, 4,

c) The icosahedral group, when p, q, r = 2, 3, 5.

I am working with question b), that is $<x,y,z|x^2,y^3,z^4,xyz>$

have $xyz = 1$ and $x^2 = 1$

I get $yz = x^{-1} = x$ and $yzyz=1$

Then $<y,z|y^3,z^4,yzyz>$ is homomorphic to $<x,y,z|x^2,y^3,z^4,xyz>$

I chose $H=<y>$ and found the $y=(243)$ $z=(1234)$ is the solution of $<y,z|y^3,z^4,yzyz>$, the detailed process is in the followed image:

[image]

I found when I set a = 3, I will get b = 2 and c = 4, also all tables are passed.

Then the order is $|G|=|H|[G:H]=3\times4=12$

But the order of octahedral group is 24, what in my answer is wrong?

Comment: How can we possibly tell what you have done wrong when you haven't shown the details of your calculation? You should get $8$ cosets of $H$, and something like $y=(2,3,5)(4,6,7)$, $z=(1,2,4,3)(5,7,8,6)$.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt, I added some details. I think your results are right, as your [G:H] is 8.

Comment: But you are not allowed to just guess entries in the tables, even if your guesses seem to work. All of your table entries have to be either definitions, or they have to be deduced from the tables. If you guess entries then the result might be a proper quotient of the group defined by the presentation. In this example, your permutations do generate $S_4$, but you have made the stabilizer larger than $H$, because $zyz$ fixes $1$. If you do the algorithm correctly, then the stabilizer of $1$ should be exactly $H$.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt. So, I should add rows to complete the table as I get uncertain entries.

Comment: Hi, @DerekHolt, I expand my table from 1-4 to 1-8, still I get lots of uncertain entries, can you show me how you get your results? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary of coset enumeration of the cosets of $H$. We know that $1y=1$.

Define $1z=2$, $2z=3$, $3z=4$, deduce $4z=1$.

Deduce $2y=4$ from $1yzyz=1$.

Define $4y=5$, deduce $5y=2$.

Define $5z=6$, $6z=7$, $7y=8$, deduce $8z=5$.

Deduce $6y=3$ from $4yzyz=4$.

Deduce $3y=8$ from $5yzyz=5$, and hence $8y=6$.

Finally, deduce $7y=7$ from $8yzyz=8$.